# Calling composable funciton from mouseclickable

Tags: kotlin

I need to show a cursorDropDownMenu if there was a click with the secondary button on an Item.
My code which calls the function is the following:

```
    .mouseClickable {
            if(buttons.isSecondaryPressed){
                showContextmenu()
            }else {
               //same as in clickable
            }
        }
```

my showcontextmenu function is the following:

```
@Composable
fun showContextmenu(){
    println("rightclick detected")
    CursorDropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = {/*todo implement? */ }){
        DropdownMenuItem({/*onclick: todo get data and forward it to render the gui tree */}){
            Text("render")
        }
    }
}
```

But the compile error is that @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @composable function.

Some help would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean state var to show/hide menu.

```
var isContextMenuVisible by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}

//...
//your button code
.mouseClickable {
    if(buttons.isSecondaryPressed){
        isContextMenuVisible = true
    }else {
        //same as in clickable
    }
}
//...
if (isContextMenuVisible) {
    ShowContextmenu()
}
//...
```

And:

```
@Composable
fun ShowContextmenu(){
    println("rightclick detected")
    CursorDropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = {isContextMenuVisible = false}){
        DropdownMenuItem({/*onclick: todo get data and forward it to render the gui tree */}){
            Text("render")
        }
    }
}
```